# Unable to parse JSON response of `foundation blocks list` foundation-cli command

Tags: json, zurb-foundation

I installed `yarn` via `scoop`. And installed `foundation-cli` as global with `yarn`.

When I execute `foundation blocks list`, an error shows:

```
error fetching file /building-blocks/data/building-blocks.json
undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Object.parse (native)
at C:\Users\rairo\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\foundation-cli\lib\commands\blocks.js:28:23
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rairo\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\foundation-cli\lib\util\fetch-url.js:24:9)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Upon further checking, it seems the response is blocked with captcha. I opened incognito mode in Chrome and accessing https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/data/building-blocks.json indeed it shows a captcha screen. Is this expected? Any workaround? thanks!

Versions:
Foundation CLI version 2.2.3
yarn v0.27.5
npm 3.10.10
node 6.11.0 via nvm

Comment: Most likely they don't like the fact that the endpoint is being hit far too often.  It seems that they throttle by IP -since incognito mode renders the Captcha-. Unless you have a pool of IP addresses that you can query from, I don't think there's much you can do. Why not catching the response? Does it change often?

Comment: @Icarus, thanks for the reply, I think you're right. Will check first if I can do a workaround. Just curious if there was anything I did wrong in the installation and it didn't work out of the box.